# Agregar elemento a una tupla en python

Tags: python

Actualmente tomo un archivo de excel y extraigo los datos de una hoja con openpyxl, lo cual me arroja un objeto con varias tuplas de cada fila del excel, estas filas las guardo en un arreglo (baseBitacora) para luego tomar cada "línea" o tupla y agregarle la fecha, para luego guardarlo en otro excel.

Este es mi código.

```
l_Alerta = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:/Plantilla.xlsm",read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
h_Alerta = l_Alerta.worksheets[0]

lBitacora = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:/Bitacora.xlsm",read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
hBitacora = lBitacora.worksheets[0]

baseBitacora = []
baseBitacora2 = []
a = []

h_bitacora = hora_Ejecucion.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M")

print("AGREGANDO DATOS a baseBitacora ")
for row in h_Alerta.values:
    baseBitacora.append(row)
    
print("AGREGANDO HORA EN LA BITACORA") #Aca es donde me da error y no logro unir los datos del excel con la hora
for row in baseBitacora:
    a = row
    baseBitacora2 = a.append(h_bitacora)
    print("baseBitacora2 ",baseBitacora2)

print("AGREGANDO DATOS EN LA HOJA BITACORA")    
for row in baseBitacora2:
    print(row)
    hBitacora.append(row)        
    
lBitacora.save("D:/bitacora.xlsm")
lBitacora.close()
l_Alerta.close()
```

Comment: Una lista usa corchetes [] y una tupla paréntesis (). No puedes agregar elementos a una tupla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice mateo, es imposible agregar un item en una tupla. Sin embargo, existen otras alternativas:

#### Crear una nueva tupla.

Es posible hacer algo similar a agregar un elemento a una tupla, y es sumarle otra tupla. Esto va a crear una tercera tupla con los elementos de la primera tupla seguidos por los de la segunda:

Ejemplo:

```
print((1,2,3) + (4, 5, 6))
```

Produciría (1,2,3,4,5,6).

También podés usar el maravilloso desempaquetado dentro de la sintaxis de la tupla:

```
print((*(1,2,3), *(4,5)))
print((*(1,2,3), 4))
```

Que produciría:

```
(1,2,3,4,5)
(1,2,3,4)
```

Ten en cuenta que la tupla original, al ser inmutable, queda inalterada. Esto significa que si guardas una tupla en una variable y sumas otra tupla (obviamente sin usar +=, que hace la suma y la guarda en la variable), la variable no habrá cambiado:

```
a = (1, 2)
print(a + (3, 4))
print(a)
```

Produciría:

```
(1,2,3,4)
(1,2)
```

Algo similar pasa con las listas, ya que durante la suma, se crea una nueva lista. Pero podrías encontrarte algún día con el escenario de que la suma altere al elemento original (aunque esto no es habitual, es posible).

Hay que saber diferenciar cuando el código (al menos en Python) crea algo nuevo o modifica lo original. Recuerda que las variables son en realidad nombres que les das a los objetos.

#### Convertirla a una lista

El objeto mutable más cercano a una tupla al cual se pueden agregar elementos es una lista. Simplemente convierte la tupla en lista usando la función `list`, agrega el dato con append y después, en caso de que si o si deba ser una tupla, podés usar `tuple` para convertir la lista en tupla nuevamente.

```
a = (1,2,3)

a = list(a)
a.append(4)

a = tuple(a_list)

print(a)
```

Debería de producir:

```
(1,2,3,4)
```